# How to make HTML table cell content to occupy all the cell rows?

Tags: html, css

I have this table - http://jsfiddle.net/mark69_fnd/cgwyJ/

Notice, the last column - Notes, it spans all the rows.

How can I make its content to occupy all the rows, rather than cause the table to be the width of the page?

I am looking for something like http://jsfiddle.net/mark69_fnd/cgwyJ/4/, **only without resorting to the width css parameter**.

**EDIT**

Exhibit A:

[image]

Exhibit B:

[image]

**EDIT 2**

1. I am not looking for a fixed width table. I just want the row spanning cell to utilize the vertical space efficiently.
2. Please, do not provide answers involving the width. If you think either width or <br/> are needed, then you can just reply with "Nope, that's impossible".

**EDIT 3**

OK, there is a great deal of confusion around my question. Probably, because it is not formulated clearly.

Of course, there is a width limit involved somewhere underneath, but it is not a constant. It cannot be baked into the CSS. This is because it is a function of the following parameters:

- The height of the available vertical space (`N`)
- The average height of the characters **in the given font** (`A`)
- The length of the given text, when presented on a single line, again **in the given font** (`B`)

Given these parameters, the required width is `A * B / N`. So, there is a well defined way to formulate what I want, but you just cannot express it with a constant width. So, my question is this - are there means to achieve this declaratively (i.e. in HTML/CSS) using some other attributes/properties?

Hope this clarifies a bit the picture.

Comment: Here both fiddles look the same.

Comment: Why don't you want to use CSS `width`?

Comment: Because it is affected by the font and the font may change.

Comment: Chrome lastest they look exactly the same. I did not -1 the question btw.

Comment: @CristianoFontes the difference is that the second table has a specified width. the first one does not, so the long string in the notes column causes the table to get wider. OP wants it to take advantage of the vertical space, breaking automatically, instead of widening the cell.

Comment: @mark question: what would you expect it to do when there is more content than space? the current behavior (make fiddle 1 window really small) the cells of the last row get taller to make the content fit.

Comment: @sachleen - That's a tough question. I have already noticed this behavior. Ideally, the cells should be equal sized, however, I realize that doing so may required javascript, so I do not care. As long as the row spanning content uses the vertical space efficiently, I do not mind the last row being of different height.

Comment: @mark the problem you have is that you want the table to have a fixed width but you claim to not want that. How do you decide where to break to the next line?

Comment: @sachleen - I have never mentioned to want the fixed width. Have I? Where, so I can fix the question.

Comment: I'm saying by saying you want the lines to split to take advantage of the vertical space, at what point should it break a line? That point is defined by a fixed width.

Comment: @sachleen - Please, agree with me that what I am asking is achievable by writing some javascript code without relying on the fixed width. So there is a way to do it without having a width baked into the CSS. Now, all I am asking is whether there is a declarative way to request this behavior, through some HTML attributes and/or CSS properties. If you think there is none, well, maybe you are right, but then maybe you are wrong.

Comment: @mark I don't know what you want to achieve, though, so I can't say there is a way. You want to break a line of text into multiple lines to fill up vertical space. Where do you break it up... how wide should each line be? If you don't know that, how do you expect to tell the computer to do it?

Comment: @sachleen - Given: vertical space `N` pixels high, a text, when presented on a single line - `A` pixels high and `B` pixels long. Then the text could be split in `N / A` lines. Which means, the length of the text becomes `B / (N / A) = (A * B) / N` pixels. So, the last cell should be roughly `(A * B) / N` pixels in width. This is the algorithm, which does not rely on a width baked in the CSS. Of course, at the end it calculates a width, but this width is a function of the current font and the given text. No constant magic widths.

Comment: What if the value of the notes column is only a single word? Also I don't think this is possible with only CSS+HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Either `<br/>` The Paragraph or just resort to the `width: ;` CSS Parameter, and Why wouldn't you want to do that?

but line breaking (`<br/>`) it all would be the only other option I can think of.

Comment: Because width is affected by the font. What renders nice with one font will be rendered badly in another, because the width does not take it into account.

Comment: @KevinBoucher - I beg your pardon?

Comment: Yes if you were to do this, that is the only down side

Answer (score 0):

Honestly the CSS way is the best if you ask me, but you could always set the width to that paragraph cell, the problem with that is if there is too much text it will make the bottom row taller than the others.

http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/cgwyJ/6/

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Browser</th>
  <th>http --&gt; http</th>
  <th>http --&gt; https</th>
  <th>Notes</th>  
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>Chrome</td>
  <td>CORS</td>
  <td>CORS (*)</td>
  <td rowspan="3" width="280">If the SSL certificate validation fails, neither CORS nor JSONP will work. However, there is a workaround. The respective request .
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Firefox</td>
  <td>CORS</td>
  <td>CORS (*)</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: I do not want any explicit width parameters. They screw the layout if a different font is used.

Comment: @mark you're completely missing the point: it HAS to cut off the lines at some width. If you disagree, that's the current behavior where it stretches horizontally. You have to know *where* you want it to split lines or it doesn't split lines. And if you know where you want it to split lines, that's a fixed width. no?